# Desperately Seeking Niven: "A combinatorial problem of finite sequences," Nieuw Arch. Wisk. 16 (1968), 116–123

Tags: reference-request

I would like an electronic copy of the article by Ivan Niven entitled "A combinatorial problem of finite sequences," Nieuw Arch. Wisk. 16 (1968), 116–123.

If anyone has a link to that article, I would appreciate it, please.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered by a Google search, as pointed out by [@VladimirDotsenko](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461213).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick Google search shows that most of Nieuw Arch. Wisk. is digitized; you can find the relevant volume [here](https://resolver.kb.nl/resolve?urn=KBKWG02:022186001:00003).

Comment: Link to the first page: [Niven - A combinatorial problem of finite sequences](https://www.delpher.nl/nl/tijdschriften/view?coll=dts&identifier=KBKWG02%3A022186001%3A00125).

Comment: Thank you. (My not-so-quick Google search yielded nothing.)

Comment: @Tri just for historical record (and for possible benefit of a random reader), I can say that Google search brought me to the page https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/t.h.koornwinder/dutchmathjournals/NieuwArchief.html - where one can be discouraged by the fact that the third series does not seem to be available, but clicking at the link for the second series and searching through the website it brings works like a charm!